# Error in matrix dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I am trying to model a vector data containing 200 sample points denoting a measurement.I want to see "goodness of fit" and after reading I found that this can be done by predicting the next set of values(I am not that confident though if this is the correct way).I am stuck at this since the following code gives an error and I am just unable to solve it.Can somebody please help in removing the error

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in data_predict (line 27)
    ypred(j) = ar_coeff' * y{i}(j-1:-1:j-p);
```

Also,can somebody tell me how to do the same thing i.e get the coefficients using nonlinear AR modelling,moving average and ARMA since using the command nlarx() did not return any model coefficients?
**CODE**

```
if ~iscell(y); y = {y}; end
model = ar(y, 2, 'yw');

%prediction
yresiduals=[];
nsegments=length(y);

ar_coeffs = model.a;
ar_coeff=[ar_coeffs(2) ar_coeffs(3)]
for i=1:nsegments
  pred = zeros(length(y{i}),1);
  for j=p+1:length(y{i})
    ypred(j) = ar_coeff(:)' * y{i}(j-1:-1:j-p);
  end
  yresiduals = [yresiduals; y{i}(p+1:end) - ypred(p+1:end)];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In matlab, `*` is the matrix product between two matrices. That means that the number of columns in the first matrix must equal the number of rows in the second matrix. You might have intended to use `.*` element by element multiplication. EDIT: For element by element multiplication, the matrices must be the same size. Check the size of your matrices.  If they don't fit either of these conditions, something needs to change.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I used .* still the same error appears!